# PHP - Global variables being cleared

Tags: php, global-variables

I have a PHP file imported by a require_once() call in another PHP file that is autoloaded. In this file there are a small number of string global variables defined:

```
$foobar = "foo";
$bazqux = "baz";

class FooClass {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        global $foobar;
        $this->foo = $foobar; // $foobar is <null> here
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code the global variable $foobar is "" according to XDebug under Apache2 (I'm using VS.php as my IDE). I get the same problem when I run the script under normal PHP FastCGI under IIS .

I've gone through all my code and the symbol "$foobar" only appears in this source file so it isn't being overwritten elsewhere.

I since changed it from a global variable to a define() constant and it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the superglobal - `$GLOBALS`.

```
$this->foo = $GLOBALS["foobar"];
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
$foobar = "foo";
$bazqux = "baz";

class FooClass {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        global $foobar;
        $this->foo = $foobar;  
    }
    function display() {
      print $this->foo;
    }
}

$a=new FooClass;
print $a->display();
?>
```

Comment: Both are valid and work well at my end. You may use automatic global or superglobal $GLOBALS.

Comment: @David it is not necessary but require paying less attention (frankly - no attention at all) tho the current variable scope

Comment: It turns out that, in my PHP installation at least, globals defined in one PHP file X (which is then `include()`ed in another PHP file Y) aren't made available within Y unless you use the $_GLOBALS collection.

Answer (score 1):

Code is working fine for me. Nothing wrong with the code.  It is giving me output as `foo`:

```
$foobar = "foo";
$bazqux = "baz";

class FooClass {
    private $foo;

    public function __construct() {
        global $foobar;
        $this->foo = $foobar; // $foobar is foo here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because those two variable declarations are the first thing in the include script doesn't mean they are actually in the global scope.

Including a script from within a function (your autoloader) would make them reside in that functions local scope. You won't notice since your autoloader scope wouldn't even keep them.

Solution: Also use the `global` statement before assigning the vars topmost in your script.

Answer (score 0):

if your variable was non static you must call `$this->variable` and if your variable was static you must call `self::$variable`

for example:

```
    class Entry {

          private static $y= "";
          private $x= "";

          public function start() {
          $a=$this->x;
          $b=self::$y;
    }
  }
```